# Close window - How to determine how window was opened?

Tags: javascript, window

On one page, I have a hyperlink with `target="_blank"`.

On the target page, I have a "Close" button which uses JS to close the new tab/window.

1. If the user clicks the hyperlink, I can use JS to close the opened window. Great!
2. If the user right-clicks the link and selects "Open in new tab", my JS event can not close the window.  Boo. :-(

I understand the reasons for this, however in the second case I'd like to just not show the "Close" button if the window won't be able to be closed by Javascript.

So my question: How do I pre-determine whether the window is closeable with Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `target="_blank"`, use `target="popup1"`.
Then in your new tab detect it with:

```
if(window.name == "popup1") {
  document.body.className += " closeable";
}
```

Then:

```
<style>
.closeable #closebutton {display:block}
</style>
```

Comment: ...except to add that I can no longer open multiple target windows, nor does any subsequent window opened automatically come into focus.  I'll have to tweak the `target` so that it's a unique name every time.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes tweak the target name accordingly and use substring matching for the `window.name`.