# Is Window Close-able?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I need to know whether `window.close()` is actually going to close the window. This is not a duplicate of [Close window - How to determine how window was opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689005/close-window-how-to-determine-how-window-was-opened) because that solution relies on checking `window.name`, which is not exactly foolproof; the popup could be opened with a different name but still be close-able via `window.close()`.

I can't just check whether `window.opener` is defined or not null because in Firefox and Chrome, if the user closes the opener, `window.opener` gets set to `null`. For example:

```
// In parent window:
window.open();

// In child window:
console.log(window.opener); // outputs a Window object

// Now, click the X on the parent window.

// Continue below in child window:
console.log(window.opener); // outputs null
// However, you can still close the window!
window.close(); // closes the child window
```

On the other hand, if the user loaded a page with this code in a new tab:

```
console.log(window.opener); // also outputs null
window.close(); // doesn't work; window remains open
```

Firefox then complains in the Error Console about a script not being able to close windows not opened by scripts, and Chrome does nothing.

The reason that I need to check whether `window.close()` will close the window is that if the window remains open, I want to go to another address. I thought of doing it this way:

```
// Try to close window.
window.close();
// If the window is still open after three seconds, go to another page.
setTimeout(function(){
    // For testing purposes:
    alert("Not closed!");
    // What I want to do:
    window.location = "http://www.example.com/";
}, 3000);
```

However, a three-second lag would make my application seem slow to the user. That would not do. On my computer, a delay of 1 millisecond was sufficient to let the window close; the alert only happened if the window remained open. However, I would need someone to confirm that this is true for all computers. This also does not work:

```
try{
    // This will not throw an error regardless of
    // whether the window was actually closed:
    window.close();
}catch(e){
    // This never happens:
    console.log("Could not close window");
}
```

In short, I just need a way in JavaScript to know, either before or after calling `window.close()`, whether the window will actually close. How do I do that?

Comment: Why not just call `window.close()` *and also* change the location? Either it'll close, or it'll load the new URL.

Comment: you can easily determine if it did close, but it might be harder to tell if it will close...

Comment: @Pointy That's a good idea, actually.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just call `window.close()` and then check `window.closed` to see whether it closed.  That will also catch cases where you try to `close()` a page with a beforeunload handler and the user elects to not let it close....

Oh, and per spec `window.close()` updates `window.closed` synchronously before returning if the window is going to close, so you don't have to worry about timeouts and whatnot.