# Determine if window was opened using javascript

Tags: javascript, xss, exploit

There is now a [UXSS metasploit module](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/3759) for stock Android browsers that it would be great to have a defence against.

One such defence is to use X-Frame-Options and additionally be able to know that there is no javascript reference to the window.  My question is whether it is possible to determine that no other window holds a reference to the current window object because it was not opened using javascript.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689005/close-window-how-to-determine-how-window-was-opened) is not relevant since in this case no co-operation with the opener exists.

Comment: To my knowledge, windows do not "hold a reference" to other windows in any event.

Comment: Use `window.opener`. It's a reference to parent and is "null" if window is opened by user.

Comment: @zvona in this particular case it is not an iframe, but a popup to get around X-Frame-Options

Comment: Tried @zvona's solution? It should refer to the opener already. If your solution works you should post it as a new question and answer it: "How to defend against UXSS".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible.

However with Firefox and Chrome, calling window.close() only has an effect on windows which were opened with Javascript. Older versions of MSIE (5,6) close the window regardless, I don't know about more recent versions.

Comment: So you mean a solution to the current metasploit module is an unconditional window.close() in the opened window?